# Can't read when Vim/Neovim highlight same color as text

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting, neovim

I've been trying to take my vim/neovim game to the next level and one of the things I've been trying to do is fix the highlighting issues I've been having.  The gist of it is that at times, syntax, visual selection, and search highlighting use the same/similar color for the highlighting as the original text, making it difficult to see what has been highlighted.  Does anyone know how i might be able to fix this?  based on the first screenshot, it looks like its completely capable of doing so, I just can't seem to find a config option to make it consistent.

Here are some examples (while I was using neovim in these, the behavior is the same w/ vim):

[image: note how the some of the text is almost impossible to read while highlighted? (it was whitish before highlighting) the places highlighted in red/blue are much more how i would have expected highlighting to work all the time (the highlight color more or less matches the original text color, but when highlighted, the text color was changed to make the selection readable).] note how the some of the text is almost impossible to read while highlighted?  (it was whitish before highlighting)  the places highlighted in red/blue are much more how i would have expected highlighting to work all the time (the highlight color more or less matches the original text color, but when highlighted, the text color was changed to make the selection readable).

[image: all occurrences of "if" are highlighted. again, note how the text and highlighting are pretty much indistinguishable.]all occurrences of "if" are highlighted.  again, note how the text and highlighting are pretty much indistinguishable.

[image: note how the syntax highlighting (of the [ ] pair in this case) mostly hides what the 2 surrounding characters are. this also happens with (, ), {, and }.]note how the syntax highlighting (of the [ ] pair in this case) mostly hides what the 2 surrounding characters are.  this also happens with (, ), {, and }.

.vimrc (init.vim essentially identical):

```
syntax enable
:color peachpuff
set nocp
set wildmenu
set relativenumber
set number
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set incsearch
set nowrap
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set showcmd
set clipboard=unnamed
set laststatus=2
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
set directory=~/.vim/tmp

"sudo after opening:
cmap w!! w !sudo tee >/dev/null %

"formatting brackets and such:
inoremap {<Tab> {}<Esc>i
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<Esc>ko<Tab>
inoremap (<Tab> ()<Esc>i
inoremap (<CR> (<CR>)<Esc>ko<Tab>
inoremap [<Tab> []<Esc>i
inoremap [<CR> [<CR>]<Esc>ko<Tab>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try a different colorscheme. This plugin has loads:
https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes

I'd recommend `gruvbox`, `twilight` or `apprentice`, but there are lots of great ones, find one that works for you.

You can install this plugin to be able quickly switch to the next colorscheme:
https://github.com/xolox/vim-colorscheme-switcher

Edit: here is a list of the colorschemes that you probably have installed by default in your vim:
https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime/colors

If you want to try some without installing any plugins or anything, just do e.g. `:colorscheme evening` and see how they look. If you type `:colorscheme <CTRL-D>` you'll be shown which colorschemes are available.

Comment: thanks!  I'd actually been playing around with that extension since i posted this.  I was just having trouble finding a scheme i liked.  I like the terminal colors i have and was hoping to keep them.

Comment: Ok if you don't want to switch colorscheme, you can always edit your current one. Try and find the peachpuff.vim file and play around with it. After any changes you can either restart vim, or just `:source path/to/peachpuff.vim` to try your changes out

Comment: I was actually just typing an edit to my comment.  I actually like apprentice!  but i might also try to tweak an existing colorscheme.

i still cant help but think that it either shouldn't highlight w/ the text color, or there should be an option for it.  seems kinda sloppy, you know?

Comment: Yeah highlighting like that should have the "reverse" option set I think. But apprentice is very nice with good contrasts, I haven't had any readability issues.

Comment: i'm almost tempted to change my termnal colors to match, lol!  in any case, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome. For another option again, of changing your terminal and vim together, you could look at the base-16 repos, I really like them (although I modified my base16-monokai colorscheme after realising I couldn't read diffs easily): https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim